# Android Live Chat pre-chat field form screen shows duplicate views when exiting

Tags: liveagent, android, sdk, snap-ins

I recently implemented the Live Chat UI from the Android SDK, and have encountered an issue where it appears that when showing the screen for pre-chat fields to the live chat, upon exiting the pre-chat field screen, there are 2 instances of the UI (it flickers when exiting). The video I have linked will make this more clear.

Is this a known issue, or have I incorrectly configured the SDK or setup?

[Live Chat Pre-chat field flicker video](https://streamable.com/m8xaqq)

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Hi Ritesh - Unfortunately I don't have a solution for you. Did you find anything or any solutions?

Comment: I ended up having our own pre-chat form.